# pyside closeallwindows() different behaviour on Linux, Windows

Tags: linux, qt, python-2.7, pyside

I am developing a pyside application with python 2.7.

Under certain conditions such as "the users press X top right corner of the window" or some event occurs, I call the following code:

```
    pointer = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
    pointer.closeAllWindows()
```

My intent is to close all windows. This works well on Windows and the application sits in the system tray, therefore the user can double click there and open it again.

**However** on Linux the behaviour is different. The application keeps running but the icon in the systray disappears as well preventing the user to be able to open the window again and making the application unusable.

Anyone can suggest a solution or a reason why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: On the Linux, the systray icon is implemented as a window (if that wasn't obvious already). Are you using [setQuitOnLastWindowClosed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop)?

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea they where implemented as window. I am actually surprised that everything worked so far then =)